# AngularJS not routing properly when link is passed from function

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, routes

I am learning Angular, so here is my testapp : http://enrolin.in/test/#/students

Now here I want to search the database by name. So I created the php that returns exactly what I need. Here is the php : http://enrolin.in/test/login.php?p=fetchbyname&&name=ak
You have to replace name in the url to anything you need to search. I also created a partial page that returns absolutely correct results, here is the page: http://enrolin.in/test/#/studentSearch/ak
Everything was fine till now But **here is the problem:**

When I try to search in http://enrolin.in/test/#/students , angularJS does not route me to something like http://enrolin.in/test/#/studentSearch/ak 
but instead to the default that I have set in `$routeProvider`

Here is my angularJS (I have removed some unimportant code):

```
var app = angular
        .module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider


                .when("/students/:id", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/studentDetails.html",
                    controller: "studentDetailsController"
                })
                .when("/studentSearch/:name", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/studentSearch.html",
                    controller: "studentSearchController"
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: "/home"
                })

        })

        .controller("studentDetailsController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
            $http({
                url: "http://enrolin.in/test/login.php?p=fetchone&&id=",
                method: "get",
                params: { id: $routeParams.id }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.stud = response.data;

            })
        })
.controller("studentsController", function ($scope, $http, $route,$location) {
            $scope.searchStudent=function(){
                if($scope.name){
                    $location.url("/studentsSearch/" + $scope.name);
                }
                else{
                    $location.url("/studentsSearch/");
                }
            }

            $scope.reloadData=function(){
                $route.reload();
            }
             $http.get("http://enrolin.in/test/login.php?p=fetchall")
                                    .then(function (response) {
                                        $scope.students = response.data;
                                    })
         })
        .controller("studentSearchController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
            if($routeParams.name)
            {
            $http({
                url: "http://enrolin.in/test/login.php?p=fetchbyname&&name=",
                method: "get",
                params: { name: $routeParams.name }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.studs = response.data;

            })
        }
        else
        {
            $http.get("http://enrolin.in/test/login.php?p=fetchall")
                                    .then(function (response) {
                                        $scope.students = response.data;
                                    })
        }
        })
```

Previously everytime I wanted to put a link in html to route I used to write like `<a href="#/courses">courses</a>`
But now when I want to put it in the function instead, I am not sure what to write. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use window.location.href instead of  tag to redirect. Or you can use "hash state" to control your router in func

Comment: Hi FlowerChng, Thanks for replying. But I am very new to angular, can you, please tell me how to write that code?

Comment: Hi @akhilesh-khajuria, the native javascript window.location.href="YOUR URL" will work. 
Btw, I prefer to use angular-ui-router, it 's a better way to config and control your router.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the same name what you have mentioned in the routing config. Routing name is "/**studentSearch**/:name?" but you have used in the function as "/**studentsSearch**/".

Please try replacing `$location.url("/studentsSearch/" + $scope.name);` with `$location.path("/studentsSearch/" + $scope.name);`

Correct the naming issue and it should work.

I tried this and it works fine.

Comment: Hello, Oshadha. I just tried your fix, but it's not working. And studentDetails part is not problematic, its the studentSearch part I think.

Comment: Hi @AkhilEshKhajuria, Please try replacing $location.url("/studentsSearch/" + $scope.name); with $location.path("/studentsSearch/" + $scope.name);

Comment: I think I'm not getting the question. Could you please elaborate it more to me? Try what what I suggested in my previous comment solution with following: when("/studentSearch/:name?", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/studentSearch.html",
                    controller: "studentSearchController"
                })

Comment: Oshadha, I just asked the question again here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565899/angularjs-not-routing-properly    see if it helps